# replace elements using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML rendered out in powerapps portal and I would like to replace all the occurrence of

```
    <font size = 3>..... </font>
```

with

```
    <div class="legend">... </div>
```

I have tried the snippet below, but it didn't replace it:

```
    var $descBox = $("<font size = 3>"); $descBox.replaceAll("<div class='legend well'>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To search for existing elements, use CSS expressions in jQuery's `$()`.
- To create new elements, use HTML code in jQuery's 's `$()`.
- `.replaceAll()` is a string function. You meant [`.replaceWith()`](https://api.jquery.com/replacewith/).

i.e.

```
$("font[size=3]").replaceWith( $("<div class='legend well'>") );
```

or, shorter

```
$("font[size=3]").replaceWith("<div class='legend well'>");
```

---

Exchanging only the `<font>` elements *without* also replacing their contents requires a couple more steps.

```js
$("font[size=3]").each(function () {
  // insert new container div after each `<font>`
  var $div = $("<div class='legend well'>").insertAfter(this);

  // remove the `<font>` and append its children to the new container
  $(this).remove().children().appendTo($div);
});
```

```css
div.legend {
   color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<font size="3">
  <p>elements to keep</p>
</font>
<font size="3">
  <p>more elements to keep</p>
</font>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it and it did work , but it removed all the text inside the font element.<font size =3 >Some text here </font> become <div class='legend well'></div>

Comment: @snowflakes74 That's what `.replaceWith()` does, and I did not read a different requirement from your question. See updated answer.

Comment: great +1, I applied wrap ("font[size=3]").wrap("<div class='legend well'>"); and it did exactly what I was after.Is that correct approach?

Comment: @snowflakes74 You said you wanted to get rid of the `<font>`, and `.wrap()` does not do that. But if it works for you, that's fine. You could also set up a CSS class `font.legend` that re-formats the existing `<font>` elements and then just do `$("font[size=3]").addClass("legend")`, without replacing or adding any elements.